# get information from click on any object in the image in matlab

Tags: matlab, onclick

I work on image segmentation based on color object.. now I need to get the user click value on the object in order to use this information (click value)in another process. How can I get this value in matlab. any one can help me please.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

If you want the user to click on a plot or image and get the coordinates where they clicked, you can use [ginput](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ginput.html). For example,

```
[x,y] = ginput(1);
```

will give you the coordinates of one click. You can then use your own logic to figure out which object that corresponds to.

If this isn't what you're trying to do, you'll have to explain more clearly.

Comment: thank you for replying ... Yes I want the user to click on image(any object in the image) and get the coordinates where they click ... If I get this coordinates can i will try to apply the ginput function  ... thank you so much

Comment: sorry for this mistake ... I will continue my question... If I get the object coordinates can I treat with this object as one image?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but plot objects (i.e. [lines](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/lineseriesproperties.html#ButtonDownFcn), [patches](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/patch_props.html#ButtonDownFcn), [images](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/image_props.html#ButtonDownFcn), etc.) have a `ButtonDownFcn` callback that will execute when you press a mouse button while the pointer is over the object.

Here's a simple example (using [nested functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-39683.html) and [function handles](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f2-38133.html)) of how you could use `ButtonDownFcn` callbacks to get information about the objects selected. First, save this function in an m-file:

```
function colorFcn = colored_patches

  selectedColor = [1 0 0];  %# The default selected color

  figure;                                  %# Create a new figure
  axes;                                    %# Create a new axes
  patch([0 0 1 1],[0 1 1 0],'r',...        %# Plot a red box
        'ButtonDownFcn',@patch_callback);
  hold on;                                 %# Add to the existing plot
  patch([2 2 4 4],[1 2 2 1],'g',...        %# Plot a green box
        'ButtonDownFcn',@patch_callback);
  patch([1 1 2 2],[3 4 4 3],'b',...        %# Plot a blue box
        'ButtonDownFcn',@patch_callback);
  axis equal;                              %# Set axis scaling

  colorFcn = @get_color;  %# Return a function handle for get_color

%#---Nested functions below---

  function patch_callback(src,event)
    selectedColor = get(src,'FaceColor');  %# Set the selected color to the
                                           %#   color of the patch clicked on
  end

  function currentColor = get_color
    currentColor = selectedColor;          %# Return the last color selected
  end

end
```

Next, run the above code and save the returned function handle in a variable:

```
colorFcn = colored_patches;
```

This will create a figure with 3 colored boxes, like so:

[image]

Now, when you click the mouse over one of the colored boxes, the output from `colorFcn` will change:

```
%# Click the red box, then call colorFcn
>> colorFcn()
ans =
     1     0     0  %# Returns red

%# Click the blue box, then call colorFcn
>> colorFcn()
ans =
     0     0     1  %# Returns blue

%# Click the green box, then call colorFcn
>> colorFcn()
ans =
     0     1     0  %# Returns green
```

Comment: Thank you for replying... but this not answer for my question ....I segment the image based on objects then I display to user his image segmentation in order to let the user to pick any object in the image (by click on the object he like), in this case i need to take the information of the object which the user selected in order to make my proceesing depending on this object